# retrieve single row data in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I created a website that has multiple logins and unique informations to it.. i want to retrieve the data from one user. example my username is qwert and my password is 1234, I want to retrieve his unique information to the database. I used the sample code in [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) and it selects all the data but all I want to do is to retrieve the data from the user which is only logged in.

can anyone help me about this? any help will be much appreciated.

```
mysql_select_db("xone_login", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '$myusername' ");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['overtime'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['daily_rate'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Could you add your code here so we can see what needs doing?

Comment: You need a `WHERE` clause. `SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE username='the_logged_in_username'`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We can't know what are you trying to do without any code example.

Comment: Couple of things... w3schools is not considered a good source, as it is frequently out of date.  The `mysql_*()` functions its describing are scheduled to be removed from PHP, and they are not encouraged either. [The manual](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) recommends alternatives.

Comment: So before you invest too much time in learning the `mysql_*()` functions, I recommend you change course and learn how to use MySQLi or PDO prepared statements instead.

Comment: I'm with @Michael on this one. For your own health, safety, and wellbeing, **do not use** the default `mysql_*` functions and instead [learn how to use PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you use placeholders, your chance of suffering a company-destroying SQL injection attack are very low.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the code in SQL in that tutorial with this (and adapt the table and column names) one:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS where name ='qwert' and pass = MD5('1234')
```

And take care at sanitizing your variables in order to avoid SQL injection attacks !

Comment: I think, something about SQL inject should also be mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

```
You need to use a where clause
Also you will need to specify limits on the query to restrict the result set to 1 record

$select = "SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE username = '$user' LIMIT 0, 1";
$query = mysql_query($select) or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

//Prints the array
print_r($result);
```

Comment: This has zero SQL escaping and serves as a sterling example of what not to do.